# Is there a way to reverse engineer result of "ng build prod" in angular2?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to look at components, services and all the functions that generated this files in the first place?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929835/restore-angular-4-project-from-dist-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Components yes,
Since they are all downloaded to the user, anyone could take the time to figure out how they are structured.
The same as any other website.

For the services, anyone can see what the calls are and what is returned.
The same as any other website.

Answer (score 0):

You can look javascript code(bundled file) but you cannot see ts file since there are no mapping files. The best way to check is to open debug console F12 and see it yourself.

If you build your project in localhost with ng serve (ng build) you can see all your components and files.