# Is it possible to regenrate code which is build using ng build --prod?

Tags: angular

I dont want to share my code with my client so I am plaaning to give content of Dist folder generated using ng build --prod command.
So I want to understand how secure ng build --prod is. can my cliend do reverse engineering on this encrypted file and get my original code?

Comment: Reverse engineering from JS to Angular Application should not be possible.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684908/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-engineer-result-of-ng-build-prod-in-angular2

Comment: Yes Edric. It does.