# Is there a way to compare compiled angular production app with outdated development source?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm looking for suggestions on the best method(s) to compare (not restore) a compiled production angular app with the development source, however, the catch is that the development source is outdated and not the complete angular app that is compiled in production. Long story short, the most recent up to date development source is being withheld by a foreign development company. We do not have access to the git repo, or the most up to date source, only the compiled app on Azure and a previous version of the app. We'd like to determine what's missing and the best route forward from where we are and what we do have.

At first, I looked into tools like [ngrev](https://github.com/mgechev/ngrev), thinking it could reverse engineer any angular app files, but you need a package.json or something to go off, not just the compiled main.js.

Next, I thought maybe [debundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debundle) might help, but again that was a failed attempt.

Finally, I found a [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929835/restore-angular-4-project-from-dist-folder) asking how to restore an angular app using the only dist, and the answer was you quite literally couldn't because of how many times its compiled and minified and recompiled and minified.

Some other ideas I've had but haven't tried yet would be to compile the source I do have and check the git diff. It's just javascript, you can't hide the logic its gotta be there somewhere.

**UPDATE**: Turns out comparing the git diff of both the development source I do have built with --prod flag and the compiled app on prod is not as easy as I thought since they're minified files and you can't really git diff if you only have one line to work with. Would have been a good idea if I could get the compiled prod built but not with the --prod flag.

Another idea was to use fiddler and poke around both dev and prod to determine any differences.

Any other suggestions or methods other developers have used with a similar 
fill in the blank problem of mismatching production and dev source would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is this different from the linked question? It's not possible to bring a source to life from build artifacts.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that more, not looking to "bring to life" the angular app from the compiled production code. Although that would be great. Merely looking for methods to determine what's missing, what's different about the two versions I do have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any good way to compare minified production angular to any kind of precompiled source. Disappointing but not unexpected.