# Is there any way to restore the angular (4,5,6,any version) source code from dist folder after doing ng build --prod?

Tags: angular, production-environment, ng-build

Is there any way to restore the angular (4,5,6,any version) source code from dist folder after doing ng build --prod ?

Comment: [possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929835/restore-angular-4-project-from-dist-folder) find the answer in the link provided

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore Angular 4 project from dist folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929835/restore-angular-4-project-from-dist-folder)

Answer (score 1):

1. If no source-maps - No
2. If there are source-maps - theoretically yes, check the article “SPA source code recovery by un-Webpacking source maps” by rarecoil https://link.medium.com/72EsrCGTY1
   But practically I didn't meet such activities previously